# why the image will repeat and auto attach in listview?

Tags: android, imageview, baseadapter

This class extend baseadapter

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!imagepath[position].toString().equals("no picture")) {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagepath[position], imageview);
    }
}

public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    imageViews.put(imageView, url);
    Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
    if (bitmap != null) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } else {
        queuePhoto(url, imageView);
    }
}
```

Suppose first view should be check first only display, but now display after check.

```
if (!imagepath[position].toString().equals("no picture")) {

        titletext.setPadding(imageview.getWidth() + 5, 0, 0, 0);
        datetext.setPadding(imageview.getWidth() + 5, 0, 0, 0);
        imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagepath[position], imageview);
    } else {
        imageview.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
        titletext.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
        datetext.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    }

    titletext.setText(title[position].toString());
    categorytext.setText(category[position].toString());
    datetext.setText(date[position].toString());
```

I want the textview setpadding first only display instead of the other way round.

How to solve this?

Comment: post whole code of custom adapter. And use else with if condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is because `ListView` re-uses the `Views`, put else condition also

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (!imagepath[position].toString().equals("no picture")) {
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(imagepath[position], imageview);
    }
    else{
        imageview.setImageResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        // OR
        imageview.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: nice answer, but my first item listview still show instead of not show

Comment: @Adil Soomro, how to display the result after checking?
i had updated my code